# Varnish Error 503 Backend fetch failed

Tags: magento2, varnish

Error 503 Backend fetch failed

Backend fetch failed
Guru Meditation:

XID: 32790

Varnish cache server

After varnish and configuration, error 503 occurred during the visit. The following are my related configuration screenshots, who can help me see where the problem is? Thank you in advance.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I forgot to mention that my nginx is port 8080 and varnish is port 80

Answer (score 0):

There can be several reason for this issue, I solved this by completely removing the below line

```
.url="/health_check.php"
```

There are several documents available online for this issue, Pls check if any of these helps

https://magentip.com/magento-2-error-503-backend-fetch-failed-with-varnish-cache/
https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-knowledge-base/kb/troubleshooting/miscellaneous/troubleshooting-503-errors.html?lang=en

Answer (score 0):

Run `varnishlog -g request -q "ReqUrl eq '/health_check.php'"` to figure out why it's failing. Please add the output from the logging transaction to your original question.

Based on the logs we'll try to figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your logs to identify the actual reason of error and check the VCL configuration.

Either there could many possible reason but first check varnish health:

Wrong health_check.php location in Varnish config file

Go to Varnish configuration file (/etc/varnish/default.vcl) and find these lines

```
.probe = {
    .url = "/pub/health_check.php";
```

Change it to

```
.probe = {
    .url = "/health_check.php";
```

This is the error could be the possible two situations:

- Varnish is not able to fetch the response from Magento due to
  configuration issues There is an issue on Magento's side.
- Magento sends 5xx HTTP response code.

**To Fix Magento Issue**

Usually, they are about some file permissions. In order to find exact issue, you need to skip varnish and visit the web server directly

Please check:

https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/configuration-guide/deployment/file-system-permissions.html#

https://www.cloudways.com/blog/magento-issues/

Answer (score 0):

For me this issue got resolved when i disabled magento csp module in local

```
php bin/magento module:disable Magento_Csp
php bin/magento c:f
```